# Sql to delete category and its descendants

Tags: magento2, sql, category-tree, delete

I am working with a Magento 2 store with a very large category tree (over 10000 categories). I used `CategoryRepository` and deleted one by one but this is very time-consuming since delete a brand with 2000 descendants take about 30 minutes.

Is there any SQL to delete a category and its descendants and related data from all tables? If so is using SQL faster than using PHP code?

Edit: I don't want to delete all categories, just delete a branch of category tree.

Comment: Check this: https://blog.mdnsolutions.com/magento-2-delete-all-categories/

Answer (score 0):

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;

TRUNCATE TABLE catalog_category_entity;

TRUNCATE TABLE catalog_category_entity_datetime; 
TRUNCATE TABLE catalog_category_entity_decimal; 
TRUNCATE TABLE catalog_category_entity_int; 
TRUNCATE TABLE catalog_category_entity_text; 
TRUNCATE TABLE catalog_category_entity_varchar; 
TRUNCATE TABLE catalog_category_product; 
TRUNCATE TABLE catalog_category_product_index;

INSERT INTO `catalog_category_entity` (`entity_id`, `attribute_set_id`, `parent_id`, `created_at`, `updated_at`, `path`, `position`, `level`, `children_count`) VALUES ('1', '0', '0', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, '1', '0', '0', '1'),
('2', '3', '1', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, '1/2', '1', '1', '0');

INSERT INTO `catalog_category_entity_int` (`value_id`, `attribute_id`, `store_id`, `entity_id`, `value`) VALUES 
('1', '69', '0', '1', '1'),
('2', '46', '0', '2', '1'),
('3', '69', '0', '2', '1');

INSERT INTO `catalog_category_entity_varchar` (`value_id`, `attribute_id`, `store_id`, `entity_id`, `value`) VALUES 
('1', '45', '0', '1', 'Root Catalog'),
('2', '45', '0', '2', 'Default Category');

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;

DELETE FROM url_rewrite WHERE entity_type = 'category';
```

Comment: Sorry I dont want to delete all categories, just a branch of the category tree.